# Rhino Mocks / Repository testing - NUnit test suite fails, but single mocked unit test passes?

Tags: c#, nunit, rhino-mocks

As per my previous question: [Rhino Mocks - Testing Repository layer returns "object reference not set to instance" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122145/rhino-mocks-testing-repository-layer-returns-object-reference-not-set-to-inst)

I am having an issue when passing the NUnit test when it is run in conjunction with the other tests in the suite.

The entire test class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Rhino.Mocks;
using Assert = NUnit.Framework.Assert;
Tests.DAO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Uses the 3A method of Unit Testing; Arrange, Act, Assert.
    /// 
    /// Tests the Billing DAO
    /// </summary>
    [TestFixture]
    public class BillingTests
    {
        private IDataContextWrapper _dataContext;
        private Repository _intRepository;

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets up the following constructs for testing.
        /// 
        /// - DataContext
        /// - InternalRepository
        /// - Billing
        /// </summary>
        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void TestFixtureSetup()
        {
            _dataContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataContextWrapper>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [TestFixtureTearDown]
        public void TestFixtureTearDown()
        {
            _dataContext.Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tests adding a Billing object to the Database.
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void Add()
        {
            // Arrange
            var billing = new Billing();
            _intRepository = new Repository(_dataContext);

            // Act
            _intRepository.AddRecord(billing);

            // Assert
            _dataContext.AssertWasCalled(x => x.InsertOnSubmit(billing));
            _dataContext.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SubmitChanges());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The test attempts to remove the Billing before asserting that it no-longer
        /// exists in the database by attempting to delete it again.
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void Delete()
        {
            // Arrange
            var billing = new Billing();
            _intRepository = new Repository(_dataContext);

            // Arrange
            _intRepository.DeleteRecord(billing);

            // Assert
            _dataContext.AssertWasCalled(x => x.DeleteOnSubmit(billing));
            _dataContext.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SubmitChanges());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The test retrieves the Billing from 
        /// the database and asserts that 
        /// the original Billing and
        /// the one retrieved are the same.
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void GetRecordWhere()
        {
            // Arrange
            var list = new List<Billing> {new Billing {BillingId = 1}};
            const int testId = 1;

            _dataContext.Stub(x => x.GetTable<Billing>()).Return(list.AsQueryable());
            _intRepository = new Repository(_dataContext);

            // Act
            var result = _intRepository.GetRecordWhere<Billing>(x => x.BillingId == testId);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(result.BillingId, testId);
            _dataContext.AssertWasCalled(x => x.GetTable<Billing>());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void GetAllRecordsWhere()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the total number of Billings in the database
        /// and compares it against how many were added by the testFixture.
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void GetAllBillings()
        {
            // Arrange
            _dataContext.Stub(x => x.GetTable<Billing>()).Return(new List<Billing> { new Billing { BillingId = 1 } }.AsQueryable());
            _intRepository = new Repository(_dataContext);

            // Act
            var result = _intRepository.GetAllRecords<Billing>();

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(EnumerableQuery<Billing>), result.GetType());
            _dataContext.AssertWasCalled(x => x.GetTable<Billing>());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tests find all Billings. Expects the return type to be of IQeryable
        ///  </summary>
        [Test]
        public void FindAllBillings()
        {
            // Arrange
            _dataContext.Stub(x => x.GetTable<Billing>()).Return(new List<Billing>().AsQueryable());
            _intRepository = new Repository(_dataContext);

            // Act
            var result = _intRepository.FindAll<Billing>();

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(EnumerableQuery<Billing>), result.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

The test which has now been fixed (or rather my understanding has been fixed) passes when run on its own. But not when the tests are run together? Am i missing something in the SetUp / TearDown features of NUnit? Is the dataContext or the Repository being persisted where i want it not to be?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TestFixtureSetup` and `TestFixtureTearDown` are run once per fixture. That is, there can be only one method marked `TestFixtureSetup` and it is run exactly once and before all the tests in the fixture are run. Similarly, there can be only one method marked `TestFixtureTearDown` and that method is run exactly once and after all the tests in the fixture are run. Therefore, your variable `_dataContext` is initialzed once in the method `TestFixtureSetup` and is not disposed until `TestFixtureTearDown`. It's really hard to tell if this is what you intend or not.

If you want setup and tear down methods that are run before and after each test individually, use the attributes `Setup` and `TearDown`.

Comment: Doh! Thanks for the quick answer. That was a typo on my part. Honest :)